# Meaning of curly braces after function call in C++

Tags: c++, syntax

I am reading a blog post on the code quality of the Doom 3 source code, and I've gotten stuck on a piece of C++ code I can not make sense of. I should say that I am not a C++ programmer.

The offending code looks as follows:

```
Sys_StartAsyncThread(){                          // The next look runs is a separate thread.
    while ( 1 ){
        usleep( 16666 );                         // Run at 60Hz
        common->Async();                         // Do the job
        Sys_TriggerEvent( TRIGGER_EVENT_ONE );   // Unlock other thread waiting for inputs
        pthread_testcancel();                    // Check if we have been cancelled by the main thread (on shutdown).
    }
}
```

(taken from http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/index.php, under the topic "Unrolling the loop")

This looks to me as a closure being passed as a parameter to the return value of `Sys_StartAsyncThread()` - but to my knowledge this is not possible in C++, and also `Sys_StartAsyncThread()` is of void type, so what's going on here?

The definition of `Sys_StartAsyncThread()` can be found [here](https://dev.visucore.com/doom3/doxygen/win__main_8cpp_source.html#l00912).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a typo. According to [here](http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/doom3_unrolled.php), there should be a semicolon after `Sys_StartAsyncThread();`.

Comment: Hmm, but the same syntax is used further down in the code you linked. Specifically the calls to common->Frame() and session->Frame() ?

Comment: @Jonatan:After looking more carefully, they are just notes explaining the code (there are several areas which are not valid C++ syntax).

Comment: @JesseGood Aha! That explains a lot. Thanks for sorting that out for me.

Answer (score 4):

As people have mentioned this is just a notation that I use in order the content of each method: Unrolling the loop and methods.

In the example your provided the block between braces is actually the content of the method

> Sys_StartAsyncThread

Hop

Answer (score 2):

It's just a typo. The correct code is

```
Sys_StartAsyncThread();
    {
        // Create a thread that will block on hTimer in order to run at 60Hz (every 16 milliseconds).
        // The Thread calls common->Async over and over for Sound mixing and input generation.

        while ( 1 )
        {
            usleep( 16666 );
            common->Async();
            Sys_TriggerEvent( TRIGGER_EVENT_ONE );
            pthread_testcancel();
        }
    }
```

You can see it here http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/doom3_unrolled.php, as explained in the page you referred.

> For more details here is the fully unrolled loop that I used as a map
>   while reading the code.